# Rewrite www.domain.com/test.php to www.domain.com/test/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Okay, I'm a complete noob when it comes to editing .htaccess. I've never messed with it in all my years of building websites, and recently when trying to understand the process that goes into creating exactly what I'm looking for, it flies right over my head.

- What I am trying to do is make a link domain.com/test/ load domain.com/test.php but keep /test/ instead of changing to /test.php
- So I load domain.com/test/ and I see the page domain.com/test.php but the address bar shows domain.com/test/

If anyone could help me with this that would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test/?$ test.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Okay. I had tried that but it didn't work like I've seen so after putting that in I thought maybe there was something wrong in my test.php found out my test.php was looking for the index.css in the folder. Just had to point the css script to the exact location on my site.